# Trying to save a pdf locally on device with ngCordova

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

EDIT: Never mind. I fixed it by re-adding platforms:

1) ionic platform rm android

2) ionic platform add android

.......

I'm trying to save a pdf with ngcordova plugin $cordovaFile. But I get an error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: $cordovaFile is not defined, http://192.168.149.151:8100/js/invoice.service.js, Line: 16

I installed the plugin, included the script in index.html, getting the same error in browser and on device. am I missing something?

app.js:

```
var exampleApp = angular.module('starter', ['ionic','pdf','ngCordova'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {


if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
  // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
  // for form inputs)
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

  // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
  // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
  // a much nicer keyboard experience.
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
}
if(window.StatusBar) {
  StatusBar.styleDefault();
}
});
});
```

index.html:

```
<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

service:

```
angular.module('starter').factory('InvoiceService', ['$q', InvoiceService]);

function InvoiceService($q) {  
function createPdf(invoice) {
    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
        var dd = createDocumentDefinition(invoice);
        var pdf = pdfMake.createPdf(dd);

        pdf.getBase64(function (output) {
            resolve(base64ToUint8Array(output));
        });
        pdfMake.createPdf(dd).getBuffer(function (buffer) {
        var utf8 = new Uint8Array(buffer); // Convert to UTF-8... 
        binaryArray = utf8.buffer; // Convert to Binary...

        $cordovaFile.writeFile(cordova.file.dataDirectory, "example.pdf", binaryArray, true)
        .then(function (success) {
        console.log("pdf created");
        }, function (error) {
        console.log("error");
        });
        });
    });
}

return {
    createPdf: createPdf
};    
}
```

plugin list:

```
ionic plugin list
com.jcjee.plugins.emailcomposer 1.4.6 "Email Composer with Attachments"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.2 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.1 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 4.1.1 "File"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.2.1 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.1.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.1 "Whitelist"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.0.1 "Keyboard"
dms-MacBook-Pro:pdf-test dms$ ionic plugin list
com.jcjee.plugins.emailcomposer 1.4.6 "Email Composer with Attachments"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.2 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.1 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 4.1.1 "File"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.2.1 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.1.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.1 "Whitelist"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.0.1 "Keyboard"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I fixed it by re-adding platforms:

1) ionic platform rm android

2) ionic platform add android

Answer (score 0):

You are using '$cordovaFile' in the factory but you are not injecting that your factory/service module should be like this:

```
angular.module('starter').factory('InvoiceService', ['$q', InvoiceService, '$cordovaFile', function($q,InvoiceService,$cordovaFile) {}]);
```

Or

```
angular.module('starter').factory("InvoiceService", function($q,InvoiceService,$cordovaFile) {});
```